# Set panel to go under image < 768px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an image with a panel inside that contains contact information of the company. Those two elements are looking horrible on viewport `< 768 px`. Is it possible to push the panel under the image on viewport `< 768 px`? I tried to set a `push-right` with the Bootstrap class, but does not seem to do anything like I want.

[Demosite of the contactpage](http://vouzalis.dk/contact.html) made in Bootstrap 3.

I tried to delete all the code there is not relevant for the question:

```css
/* Track and trace */
.bs-calltoaction{
    position: relative;
    width:auto;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

    .bs-calltoaction > .row{
        display:table;
        width: calc(100% + 30px);
    }
     
        .bs-calltoaction > .row > [class^="col-"],
        .bs-calltoaction > .row > [class*=" col-"]{
            float:none;
            display:table-cell;
            vertical-align:middle;
        }

            .cta-contents{
                padding-top: 10px;
                padding-bottom: 10px;
            }

                .cta-title{
                    margin: 0 auto 15px;
                    padding: 0;
                }

                .cta-desc{
                    padding: 0;
                }

                .cta-desc p:last-child{
                    margin-bottom: 0;
                }

            .cta-button{
                padding-top: 10px;
                padding-bottom: 10px;
            }

@media (max-width: 991px){
    .bs-calltoaction > .row{
        display:block;
        width: auto;
    }

        .bs-calltoaction > .row > [class^="col-"],
        .bs-calltoaction > .row > [class*=" col-"]{
            float:none;
            display:block;
            vertical-align:middle;
            position: relative;
        }

        .cta-contents{
            text-align: center;
        }
}


.bs-calltoaction.bs-calltoaction-info{
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #5bc0de;
  border-color: #46b8da;
}


.bs-calltoaction.bs-calltoaction-info .cta-button .btn {
  border-color:#fff;
}

.abc {
  position: relative;
}
.def {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
  max-width: 300px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .def {
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      max-width: 480px;
      width: 95%;
      height: 85%;
  }
.panel.panel-default .panel-heading { 
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
.panel.panel-default .panel-body {
  padding: 5px;
}
img.img-responsive {
  height: 200px;
}

}

/* Grid css */
    p.bottom-column-color {
      font-size: 0.82em;
      color: green;
    }
    
    .index-content a:hover {
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .index-content .row {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .index-content a {
      color: black;
    }
    .index-content .card {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      padding: 0;
      -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
      -moz-border-radius: 4px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }
    .index-content .card:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 16px 24px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 6px 30px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 8px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      color: black;
    }
    .index-content .card img {
      width: 100%;
      border-top-left-radius: 4px;
      border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    }
    .index-content .card h4 {
      margin: 20px;
    }
    .index-content .card p {
      margin: 20px;
      opacity: 0.65;
    }
    .index-content .cta {
      width: 235px;
      -webkit-transition: background-color 1s, color 1s;
      /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
      transition: background-color 0.5s, color 0.5s;
      min-height: 20px;
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: #ffffff;
      border-radius: 4px;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: lighter;
      margin: 0px 20px 15px 20px;
      padding: 5px 0px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .index-content .cta:hover {
      background-color: #dadada;
      color: #002E5B;
    }
    /* Set width between block elements */
    .small-padding.top {
       padding-top:10px;
    }

    .small-padding.bottom {
        padding-bottom:10px;
    } 
    .small-padding.left {
        padding-left:5px;
    }

    .small-padding.right {
        padding-right:5px;
    }

    .row [class*="col-"] {
      padding-left: 5px;
      padding-right: 5px;
    }

    .margin_bottom {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .row [class*="col-"] {
      padding-right: 5px;
      padding-left: 5px;
    }
    .row {
      margin-left: -5px;
      margin-right: -5px;
    }
    .card-img-bottom {
      color: #fff;
      height: 20rem;
      background: url(images/img1.jpg) center no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    .img-responsive { 
        height: 100%;
    }
    
    /* Set full width on columns */
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
        .img-responsive {
        width: 100%;
        }
        .index-content .card img {
        height: 100%
      }
    }

    @media (max-width: 991px) {
      h3 {
        font-size: 1.2em;

      }
    }

    /* GRID ELEMENTS MEDIA QUERIES */
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .card {
        position: relative;
      }
      .card-content {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      }
      .card-content h4,
      .card-content p {
        color: white;
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        margin: 0 0 5px;
      }
      .card-content a {
        float: right;
      }
      .index-content .card h4,
      .index-content .card p {
        padding: 15px 20px;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .index-content .card p {
        padding: 0 20px 15px;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .card-content-textbox {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
        /*right: 0;*//* top position on right*/
        margin: 15px;
        max-width: 300px;
        height: 91%
      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Kontakt Test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- TrustBox script -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//widget.trustpilot.com/bootstrap/v5/tp.widget.bootstrap.min.js" async></script>
  <!-- End Trustbox script -->
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- Picture Column -->
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="abc">
       <img src="http://vouzalis.dk/Static/Cms/05ac4ebf-d478-49a7-8567-03257ece223b.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
       <div class="def" style="width:400px;">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
             <div class="panel-heading"><h4>CompanyName A/S</h4></div>
             <div class="panel-body">
              <p><a href="#" target="_blank">Nyhåbsvej 16 - 18</a><br/>
              8560 Kolind
              </p>
              <hr/>
              <i class="fas fa-phone fa-2x"></i><a href="tel:+4586392900" style="padding-left:10px;font-size: 15px;">+ 45 86 39 29 00</a><br/><br/>
              <i class="far fa-envelope fa-2x"></i><a href="mailto:info@CompanyName.dk" style="padding-left:10px;font-size: 15px;">info@CompanyName.dk</a>
              <hr/>
              <h5>Åbningstider</h5>
              <p>Mandag - Torsdag: 8.00 - 16.00</p>
              <p>Fredag: 8.00 - 15.00</p>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, try this code:

```
 @media (max-width: 993px) {

          .def {
             position: relative;
             top: auto; 
             right: auto; 
          }
        }
     @media (max-width: 480px){
         .def {
            position: relative;
            top: 167px;
            right: auto;
          }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Ray. I just tried your suggestion here: http://vouzalis.dk/kontakt-test.html. I can see the image is gone below `< 768px;`

Comment: It did not work @Ray :-) See the link: http://vouzalis.dk/kontakt-test.html

Comment: Below `< 480 px` the image disapear. Below `< 768 px` they are not taking full width.

Comment: Hello again. I am sorry but it is still not working `< 480 px` :-( Look here: http://vouzalis.dk/kontakt-test.html

Comment: my bad, try it again

Answer (score 0):

Or you could wrap the image in one column and the panel in another, for example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Picture Column -->
        <div class="abc">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-12">
                <img src="http://vouzalis.dk/Static/Cms/05ac4ebf-d478-49a7-8567-03257ece223b.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12">
                <div class="def" style="width:400px;">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4>CompanyName A/S</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p>
                                <a href="#" target="_blank">Nyhåbsvej 16 - 18</a>
                                <br/> 8560 Kolind
                            </p>
                            <hr/>
                            <i class="fas fa-phone fa-2x"></i>
                            <a href="tel:+4586392900" style="padding-left:10px;font-size: 15px;">+ 45 86 39 29 00</a>
                            <br/>
                            <br/>
                            <i class="far fa-envelope fa-2x"></i>
                            <a href="mailto:info@CompanyName.dk" style="padding-left:10px;font-size: 15px;">info@CompanyName.dk</a>
                            <hr/>
                            <h5>Åbningstider</h5>
                            <p>Mandag - Torsdag: 8.00 - 16.00</p>
                            <p>Fredag: 8.00 - 15.00</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your suggestion. It is unfortuanllly not working `< 768 px`. I tried your code here: http://vouzalis.dk/heriuos.html